# Automator won't execute my bash shell script

Tags: automator, bash, script, command-line, automation

I have a **bash script** that works like a thread. Now I'd like to turn it into a service with Automator.

Input is set to **Image Files** in Automator and the shell script action is set to **`Pass input as arguments`**.

### The problem:

Automator takes issue with two things:

1. The function
2. The if condition

However, no error shows up in the log and the shell script result is empty:

```
(
  ""
)
```

### What the script does:

The **function** `createDatePath` checks if the passed image is formated like `2020-08-10-demo_image.jpg` and creates a folder `YEAR/MONTH/` in the target directory. The **if condition** performs actions on the input depending on whether it's an JPEG or an PNG, and whether the date string is followed by a `-qq-` string. This is a trimmed down version of the script (I have some of more if conditions, but we don't need them here I guess).

### The script:

```
backup=/Users/me/Desktop/A/backup/
targetPath=/Users/me/Desktop/A/output/

function createDatePath {
    [[ "$i" =~ ^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}) ]] && \
    mkdir -p "$targetPath${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
}
for i in "$@"; do
    cp "$i" "$backup"
    if [[ "$i" =~ ^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([^q]{2}).+\.((jpg)|(jpeg))$ ]]; then
        createDatePath;
    else
        exit 0;
    fi
done
```

**Screen shot:**

[image: Demo Mode]

**Link to complete shell script:** https://gist.github.com/pattulus/a89be63478174853d667

If anyone could explain to me why this doesn't work and how to make it work that'd be great.

*PS: In the non-Automator script the first thing I did was `cd` into the source path, but I since this will end up as a service which takes files as input my guess was that I can omit this (adding `cd "$@"` didn't do any good).*

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Automator workflow (or a link to a screenshot at least)?

Comment: @patrix I added a screen shot and a link to a Gist of the complete script. When this works I'll delete the "Get Finder selection" action and set input to receive images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments Automator passes to the script are absolute paths. You can convert them to basenames with something like `i=${i##*/}`.

Comment: You really deserve my hand-crafted badge of honor for being in the right place at the right time.